# Windows 8 App NTLM auth

Tags: soap, windows-8, ntlm

I programmed a programm in C# which accesses a web service with NTLM auth (Sharepoint 2010 server via SOAP). Now i want to port this programm to a Windows 8 app.

In my programm i used the following setting in my App.config to allow using the Windows login credentials:

```
<security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
   <transport clientCredentialType="Ntlm"/>
</security>
```

Since this isn't possible in a Windows 8 app, how can I still achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to code it manually. I've been able to connect to my SP using:

BasicHttpBinding MyHttpBinding = new BasicHttpBinding();

MyHttpBinding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport;

MyHttpBinding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Ntlm;